# python regex, only digit between whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings and at some particular index i want to check if the next char is digit surrounded by one or more whitespaces.

For example

here is a string

> 'some data   \n 8   \n more data'

lets say i am iterating the string and currently standing at index 8, and at that position i want to know that if the next char is digit and only digit ignoring all the whitespaces before and after.

So, for the above particular case it should tell me `True` and for string like below

> 'some data   \n (8   \n more data'

it should tell me `False`

I tried the pattern below

```
r'\s*[0-9]+\s*'
```

but it doesn't work for me, may be i am using it incorrectly.

Comment: Try `r'\s[0-9]+\s'` (although I always end up getting my regex' wrong when not testing)

Comment: Why a regex at all? Why not split on whitespace and check the splits?

Comment: Do you want true or false for this string: `'some data \n 8976 \n more data'`?

Comment: @jpmc26, its just an example

Comment: Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my question due to which i got -1 vote??? People SHOULD give reason instead of just - vote. This is not FAIR.

Comment: ...? I'm not sure what you mean by "just an example". I was asking what behavior you were looking for because it would affect the answer. As for the -1, it wasn't me, but while it's highly recommended to provide suggestions, it's not required and is not "unfair" if the down-voter doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original regex didn't work because the "*" is saying "zero or more matches".  Instead, you should use a "+", which means "one or more matches".  See below:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'some data \n 8 \n more data'
>>> if re.search("\s+[0-9]+\s+", s): print True
...
True
>>> s = 'some data \n 8) \n more data'
>>> if re.search("\s+[0-9]+\s+", s): print True
...
>>> s = 'some data \n 8343 \n more data'
>>> if re.search("\s+[0-9]+\s+", s): print True
...
True
>>>
```

If you just want to capture a single digit surrounded by one or more spaces, remove the "+" in front of "[0-9]" like this:

```
re.search("\s+[0-9]\s+", s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<=\s)[0-9]+(?=\s)
```

This regex uses a look-ahead and a look-behind, such that it matches the number only when the characters before and after it are whitespace characters.

In verbose form:

```
(?<=\s) # match if whitespace before
[0-9]+  # match digits
(?=\s)  # match if whitespace after
```

Comment: @zhangyangyu Well there will be at least one space, and we don't match the whitespace anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Without regex:

```
s1 = 'some data \n 8 \n more data'
s2 = 'some data \n (8 \n more data'

testString = lambda x: True if len(x.splitlines()[1].strip()) == 1 else False

print testString(s1)
print testString(s1)
```

Output:

```
True
False
```